# Proper term for dog waste

Tags: word-choice

Can you please check my sentences below or write new sentences that sound natural for me?

> Be careful! Dog's poop just ahead.
>   There's a lot of dog's waste on this street. Mind your step.
>   Be careful! There's so much dog shit.

Should I say *dog's poop*, *dog shit*, or *dog's waste*?

For *poop*, I wonder if it should be singular or plural. Can I say "Be careful! Dog's poops!"?

Comment: What is "-1"? I really want to know about it? Is it impolite question??? I need to warn my foreigner friends about that. Please have positive thinking!

Comment: Some suggestions: Don't use "dog's"; use just "dog". Don't use "shit": it's vulgar. You can say "dog poop" if you want: low register. You can say "dog excrement": much higher register. You can say "dog dung" or "dog feces": middle register. Or you can say "dog droppings": but "droppings" is usually used for birds, so unless they're bird dogs, you might not want to say that. Choose the word that your audience will understand and appreciate. Maybe a picture would be better: use Google Images. Then you don't need to choose a descriptive phrase. Sometimes things are better left unsaid.

Comment: No, the question isn't impolite, but maybe it's off topic. Somebody thought you asked the wrong kind of question: _Will you please write something for me?_ It's like asking us to do your homework. But I think it's a reasonable request.

Comment: I don't understand the Off Topic closevote. The mere fact that @Bill can suggest *dung* and *droppings* (which both sound really weird to me) simply underlines the fact that even native speakers may struggle to find suitable terms.

Comment: Thank you so much Bill Franke and FumbleFingers!  I searched for informations and copied those sentences from internet and online dictionary.I wasn't sure they were polite to say or not so I asked here to get proper sentences. Your explanations are very useful and helpful.

Comment: @Bill Franke  Thanks for teaching about dropping too. I don't know before that it is used for birds. It's very useful. All explanations from everyone about English here are important for me.

Comment: It appears to be a common problem, we need a new single word for the stuff, particularly when stuck between the grooves on athletic shoes.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What is a "bird dog"?!

Comment: @Konrad: I'm not sure why you're asking *me*, since I never used either of the words "bird" or "dog". I'm not 100% sure, but I imagine user264 was making a rather fanciful pun conjuring up an image of flying dogs crapping on people from above (the way pigeons do in many of the world's big cities). In other contexts, a "bird dog" is the standard term for a specific type of [gun dog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun_dog) used to flush pheasants etc. out of the undergrowth into the air so people can shoot them. Then the bird dog retrieves the shot birds for the "hunters".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ooops, I confused the two comments, because **user264** wasn't clickable. My bad. Also - awesome guess on the bird dogs.   :)

Comment: I have never in my life heard dog dung. Horse dung, sure.

Answer (score 5):

The RSPCA (UK-based, Royal Society for the Prevention of Cruelty to Animals) has a publication called *Complete Dog Care Manual*, which [includes a section](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NxROBthDeEgC&pg=PA37&dq=%22dog%20mess%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Y36KUdD0FtCr0AWC_4HwCA&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22dog%20mess%22&f=false) headlined

> Cleaning up **dog mess**.

So I'd go for that if you're not sure how others might react to various different words (for example, *poop* may be considered "childish", *shit* may be a bit too crude, and *waste* is somewhat "clinical").

Logically, you might think **dogs' mess** would be more "correct", but in fact that form is quite uncommon.

---

Note that whenever possible, corporate/government documents, newspapers, etc., tend to avoid directly referring to the excrement itself. You probably wouldn't want to bring it up in after-dinner conversation anyway, but *"There's a problem with [dog fouling](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22dog+fouling%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in our local park"* might be more acceptable there.

---

UPDATE: Intrigued by some of the comments, I dug deeper. It turns out [**Americans** favour "poop"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dog%20mess,dog%20poop,dog%20dirt&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)...

(NGrams, "American English" corpus)

[image]

...whereas [**Brits** favour "mess" or "dirt"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dog%20mess,dog%20poop,dog%20dirt&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=)...

(NGrams, "British English" corpus)

[image]

Note that I didn't include ["shit"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dog%20mess,dog%20poop,dog%20dirt,dog%20shit&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) in those charts. It's actually far more common than all the alternatives put together, but in many contexts it would definitely be far too vulgar to use safely.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanations and new words! It's also helpful and useful.

Comment: Incidentally, "Dogs' mess" means that the mess was made by multiple dogs. If the mess was made by a single dog, it would be "Dog's." But either way, "dog" without the "s" at the end is more common in this particular context.

Comment: @jimirings: Well. obviously if you were talking about a *specific* dog turd, it would be **a dog's mess**. So in OP's first example it would be more grammatically correct to refer to it that way *in writing*. But people probably don't often *write* about individual ["steamers"](http://www.shaggybevo.com/board/archive/index.php/t-113530.html?s=e25f3051f1a2345b630d9e80747de41f) (though I admit that one was easy to find! :), so the position of the "potential apostrophe" is something of a moot point. I did check Google Books, actually - **dog mess** is by far the most common orthography there.

Comment: *Dog mess* and *dog fouling* both sound strange in U.S. English.  I suppose they're both understandable, though.

Comment: @snailboat: Well, if we're to believe Google Books UK/US classifications, and prevalence percentages, I get the impression it was [US from the 50s](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dog+mess&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=), and only really [caught on in the UK in the 80s](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dog+mess&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=). But apparently it's now three times more prevalent in the UK (we obviously like it! :)

Comment: Dog dirt? I've never heard that one. "Dog mess" sounds weird to me too. I guess that's the American vs. British thing.

Comment: @Daniel: I don't use "dirt" myself, though as my previous NGram shows, it's still about as common as "mess" in UK English. But homing in on [BrE 1950-1980](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dog+mess%2Cdog+dirt&year_start=1950&year_end=1980&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=) confirms my initial preconception that "dirt" was actually more common than "mess" a few decades ago. I recall it as the term of choice used by parents who didn't want to use the standard "shit" in front of children, in my youth.

Comment: I would have looked for *waste*, *excrement*, *droppings*, or *faeces* (or *feces*) as all being more normal.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks a lot for those charts. It's interesting and useful.

Comment: @tchrist: Having just checked, I see ***dog feces*** is in fact more common than all of *mess, poop, dirt, waste, excrement, droppings* in NGrams US, and ***faeces*** gets the top slot in UK English. But I think as with ***waste***, these are somewhat "clinical" terms that might appear on official warning notices, but wouldn't usually be used in conversational contexts. As of right now, second position in this particular "beauty context" is ***poop*** in the US, and ***mess*** in the UK, and both of those seem like standard "street terminology" to me.

Comment: You forgot *Dog Doo*, which comes in second.
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dog+doo%2C+dog+poop&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdog%20doo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdog%20poop%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

I would say dog feces in formal situations (example of use [here](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/02/05/chung-kim-texas-man-alleg_n_2623832.html)). Avoid using "shit": it's very [vulgar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shit).

Comment: In everyday conversation, just about everyone says dog shit.

Answer (score 0):

The first two sentences don't sound natural at all. It is not necessary to write "*dog's*" in that context. It would be sufficient just to write *dog*.

> Should I say dog's poop, dog shit, or dog's waste?

That would depend on circumstances. You could use the word *shit* in situations when it is acceptable or you are deliberately trying to be, crude, obnoxious. In general, it is better to use a more polite reference to it, which would be **dog mess**. That is a common way of referring to it. Another polite way of saying it would be *dog waste* but, it's not as common.

Regarding "poop", that doesn't seem natural. (The second letter P is superfluous. An unnecessary, added extra. Surplus to requirements.) I don't know where you got that from or why you used it but, in England and the rest of the UK, there is an English word in use which is **poo**. It's informal and usually used by children. It's not crude, just informal and is also used by adults when speaking informally. It is also used in the context of dog mess and is a common, alternative way of referring to it.

In general, you can write *dog mess* (or dog poo if you are being informal) in your sentences. You could also write *dog waste*.

Comment: *Poop* is perfectly normal in American English. Not exactly high-register, but totally normal.

Comment: Thank you so much Tristan! I 've ever heard that word "poo" but I thought poo is only used for children poo. I don't know that we can use in this case. It is helpful and useful.

Comment: @ Martha Thanks for your informations about "poop" because it helps me to learn about British English and American English. It's useful and interesting.

Comment: Martha, that's enlightening. I did not know that.

Comment: nkm, it's not only used in terms of children. Adults also use it, when speaking informally.

Comment: I would say that "poop" is not commonly used in British English (as illustrated in the graphs) but would probably be understood as an Americanism. I think "poo" would be perfectly acceptable in informal talk these days - but not on a written notice.

Answer (score 0):

Another term for it (British English) is **[Dog Muck](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/muck)**.

This is certainly the term I would use in an informal situation where *shit* would be inappropriate.